# How to check vscode commands that are invoked when I use a keybinding?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

I have a problem with doublepasting values into vscode's console, I would like to check what commands are run to find out what's causing the problem and I wasn't able to find out how to do it, I remember launching a command in Sublime Text that logged every command ran to editor's console and I don't know how to enable such mode in vscode.

Comment: [Troubleshooting keybindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_troubleshooting-keybindings)

Comment: It seems like the problem is more complex and is not connected to vscode, rather WSL itself, since doing copypastes in my WSL Windows Terminal work same way. Thanks for heads up though.